# Error en python selenium: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, selenium

Estimada comunidad:

Estoy intentando realizar una automatización con selenium aplicandole un explicit wait, este es el codigo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\dchrome\chromedriver.exe")

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

#nuevos para Explicit wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

def desc_evidencia(link):
    driver.get(link)
    wait= WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    boton = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='analyzeViewPrintChild']/div[3]/div[2]/div/button"))
    boton.click()
    time.sleep(0.3)

#Evidencia marzo
desc_evidencia("https://forms.office.com/Pages/DesignPage.aspx?origin=shell#Analysis=true&FormId=INj_ffQH0UW9ymuArwhzlrVe5nllTWlLq99sOE0k2kpUOVBETDY2OUdXVTFDWENZQ0ZZUVVVRlRZRi4u")

#Evidencia abril
desc_evidencia("https://forms.office.com/Pages/DesignPage.aspx?origin=shell#Analysis=true&FormId=INj_ffQH0UW9ymuArwhzlrVe5nllTWlLq99sOE0k2kpUNlQ1OEIyRDNRT1hVS1Y4OFpIS1UyMkc2Ui4u")
```

Al ejecutar el codigo, me aparece `TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`, pero cuando a la definición del boton le agrego un par extra de parentesisen la parte del Xpath `boton = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='analyzeViewPrintChild']/div[3]/div[2]/div/button")))`, el codigo funciona.

¿Por que al agregar el par extra de paréntesis el código funciona? ¿Debería definir el código de otra forma?

Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependiendo del contexto, los paréntesis se pueden usar de varias formas, por
ejemplo, para llamar funciones o crear tuplas.

```
def mostrar_mi_tupla(tupla):
    print(tupla[0], tupla[1])

mi_tupla = ("perro", 4)

mostrar_mi_tupla(mi_tupla)
mostrar_mi_tupla(("gato", 10)) # llamo a `mostrar_mi_tupla` con otra tupla
```

Con respecto al error que te dio,

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

quiere decir que el constructor de la clase `element_to_be_clickable` fue llamado
con tres argumentos (`self` implícito, `By.XPATH`, y el XPath) pero solo acepta dos,
`self` (implícito) y una tupla. Esa tupla debe tener como primer elemento el
tipo de selector que se va a usar (en este caso `By.XPATH`) y como segundo el
selector. Al agregarle parentésis dentro de los que ya se usan para crear un
`element_to_be_clickable`, estás haciendo la tupla que necesita el constructor
como argumento.

Comment: Me quedó clarisimo, muchas gracias! Y sobre el self implícito, ¿Sería adecuado explicitarlo?

Comment: @MoisesT no es necesario, es un detalle de implementación, solo lo mencione porque tambien lo cuenta para mostrar la cantidad de argumentos en el error